# Rainmeter: Multiple Profiles for W/ or W/o monitor

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, rainmeter

I have "that" 22" monitor and I use it on and off with a laptop now (not too hard with Windows 7's <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and rainmeter. The problem with Rainmeter is that it doesn't scale when I turn off the external monitor and therefore, I can't see anything on it.

Is there any way to (automatically, please) give Rainmeter profiles that can change on a change in monitor setup?

Comment: heh. Love the reference to "that" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search the Rainmeter Forums for RainRez, it's an Addon that should do just what you need.